# Add delete button on-the-fly when reviewing flags

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete, flag-queue

If you have the privilege to delete answers with negative score, a delete button is shown in the flag queue:

[image: Flag queue delete button]

But if the answer did **not** have a negative score before and I downvoted it then there is no delete button:

[image: Flag queue no delete button]

I would have to refresh the page to see the delete button. But then I lose the focus on that post or it may not even be in the current list any more and I would have to search it.

Can this button be added on-the-fly when I downvote?

Comment: Click `share`, `Ctrl+C`, `Alt+D`, `Ctrl+V`, `enter` > `F5` (not that I'd mind your proposal, if there's time to spare for implementing it...)

Comment: +1 - also, I'd like a combined "downvote, close, delete-when-closed" batch button on questions :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've added a client-side implementation of this feature into the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) v1.10.

In case you're curious, here's the JavaScript code that does it:

```javascript
if ( ! $('body.tools-page.flag-page').length ) return;
if ( SOUP.userRep < ( SOUP.isBeta ? 4000 : 20000 ) ) return;

var html = '<input title="vote to delete this answer" class="delete-post" value="delete answer" type="button">';

SOUP.hookAjax( /^\/posts\/\d+\/vote\/[023]\b/, function ( event, xhr, settings ) {
    var score = $.parseJSON( xhr.responseText ).NewScore;
    var pid = Number( settings.url.replace( /^\/posts\/(\d+)\/.*/, '$1' ) );

    // if it's not an answer, do nothing
    if ( ! $('#flagged-' + pid + ' #answer-' + pid).length ) return;

    // find *all* the delete buttons/links; there may be several!
    var button = $('[id="delete-post-' + pid + '"]');

    if ( score >= 0 ) button.hide();
    else if ( button.length ) button.show();
    else $(html).attr('id', 'delete-post-' + pid).insertAfter('#flagged-' + pid + ' .flag-post-button').before(' ');
} );
```

The `SOUP.hookAjax()` function is a small piece of utility code that monitors the jQuery AJAX requests used to submit post up/downvotes.  If an answer is upvoted (or un-downvoted) to a positive score from the review view, the event handler above hides the delete button; if it's downvoted to a score of zero or less, it re-shows it, or, if necessary, injects its own "fake" (but fully functional!) delete button.

(For an official fix, it would probably be easier to just include the delete buttons in the HTML for all answers, but hide it by default for those with a positive score.  I can't do that in a user script, so I have to hardcode the button HTML into the script.)